# Trouble getting $compile to work

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am trying to append a div that contains an angular directive to the DOM using JQuery. However, the directive is disappearing when it is appended because I am doing something wrong. For reference, I am developing in meteor using angular and JQuery and writing code in ECMAScript 6 class style.

I have done some searching and found that I have to use $compile to append an element that contains an ng-click directive. However, I can't get it to work for some reason. Here is my attempt:

```
someFunctionThatsBeenCalled() {
    var green = "<img src='greenpin.png' ng-click='chat.doStuff()' id='" + pinId + "' class='pin' style='left: " + pos + "%'/>";

    $('#progress-container').append(this.$compile(green)(this));
}

doStuff() {
    console.log("it clicked");
}
```

Note: both of these functions are within the same controller called "chat", and "this" refers to the general controller's context. I suspect I may be using the wrong value for the scope portion of $compile, but I'm not sure what else it could be other than the controller that contains these functions.

Comment: It should be `this.$compile(green)(this.chat)`, by that scope will get passed to `$compile` function

Comment: Unfortunately that gives "Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'scope' is required".

Comment: i dont think 'this' is still $scope this at that point. you would still need to reference this via a var then bind it.

Comment: I just looked at the DOM again and it turns out that 2 different pin divs are getting appended to the container. One of the pin divs has the ng-click and the other does not. Any idea why 2 different divs are getting appended?